# Should air vents in the floor be directed towards or away from walls and windows?

Tags: hvac, venting

Builder installed HVAC vents in the floor under the windows but all the vents when opened have the air flowing away from the windows into the room.  I thought the air was supposed to be towards the window to create a tempature barrier on the outside wall.

Comment: What sort of vents? Most floor vents I've seen don't offer much in the way of directionality anyway.

Comment: Vents should go to open air, not at walls.  You need much more energy to cool or heat a wall vs. air.  You want the temperature to change the air temperature not the wall temp.

Answer (score 1):

The vents should be directed away from the walls. Vents are installed at windows because that is a cooler / warmer area depending on the season this helps maintain a more uniform room temperature.